# Save istream position for later use

Tags: c++, stream, istream-iterator

I wrote the code below which should save istream iterators. What I want is to keep the iterator for later copy to a string at the given position. This works fine until I reset the stream to the beginning. The output is "teet" bis I wanted "tees". Is there any way to make an iterator independent from the stream position?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

int main(){
    std::stringstream test;
    test << "test 123456\n";

    std::istream_iterator<char> it(test);
    std::cout << *it;
    it++;
    std::cout << *it;

    test.clear();
    test.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    std::cout << *it;
    it++;
    std::cout << *it;
}
```

Comment: How about just [getting the current input position](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg)?

Comment: `istream_iterator` is an [input iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator) - those are strictly single-pass. A typical implementation just reads at the current stream position, with one element look-ahead. More generally, there's no way to read from a stream at a particular position without seeking to that position first. `istream_iterator` doesn't possess any black magic that would somehow allow it to do the impossible - it's implemented entirely in terms of the stream's public interface.

Comment: The idea was to use std::copy with two iterators but I have no idea how to do this with a streampos.